# Can we have IP address of newly created ec2 instance dynamically in a declarative Jenkins pipeline job

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, devops

I have created multiple ec2 instances using terraform by jenkins pipeline(i.e Infra Pipeline) and after the instances got created, Now i have the below pipeline(Build Pipeline) where I have to move some files to one instance and that instance Name(tags) is "main". Is there any possibility for us to get the IP Address of the main instance dynamically in to jenkins pipeline.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Test Copy') {
            steps {
                sshagent(['test']) {
                    sh "scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no symfony-deploy.yaml ubuntu@<**target server public IP**>:/home/ubuntu/test"
                }
                
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

I hope my question is clear, Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: How did you provision the instance?

Comment: I have provisioned the instance using terraform,

Comment: Then you can use TF outputs in the pipeline for this.

Comment: Hi Matt, Can you please let me know how exactly can i use it please. because i can get the public ip of the instance to a file, but how excatly can i get that populated in the pipeline step(target server public IP).